# Converting imported dates in SQL Server 2008 to standard

Tags: sql-server-2008, date

I have existing dates in our database where some dates are formatted `mm/dd/yyyy` and others are `dd/mm/yyyy`. To be able to use `MONTH()` and `YEAR()` I need to convert the dates to `yyyy/mm/dd` but it doesn't seems like there is any easy way to do this. I've tried `CONVERT()` and `DATEPART()` with no success to convert my dates to the usable format in SQL Server 2008

My last resort is changing the 384 different dates this way.

```
UPDATE Hardware_RefreshData 
SET InstallDate = '2014/9/9' 
WHERE InstallDate = '9/9/2014
```

My goal is to be able to report on a specific month like this.

```
SELECT 
    InstallDate, 
    MONTH(InstallDate) AS Month, 
    YEAR(InstallDate) AS Year, 
    COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM 
    Hardware_RefreshData
GROUP BY 
    InstallDate
ORDER BY 
    YEAR(InstallDate) DESC, MONTH(InstallDate) DESC
```

Does anyone know of a better way to do this?

Comment: Do you mean in different tables? If not & you see `01/02/1990` how do you know if its jan or feb?

Comment: What is the type of the columns? Dates have **no format**, they are binary values. If you stored date *literals* with different formats in *text* columns, you've already lost data. There is no way to say whether 4/2/2014 is April 2 or February 2 if both formats they occur in the same column. If on the other hand the column's type is `datetime`, `date` etc you shouldn't have any problem applying date functions to them, converting them etc.

Comment: The only real fix is to use the *proper* column type, ie `date`, to store date values

Comment: 2015 was set to mm/dd/yyyy but prior it was set to dd/mm/yyyy as we changed systems and process. the InstallDate Column is set to varchar in the SQL Server. we have had different people in charge of the refresh and bad decisions were made. i have to somehow fix it though. ill ask to change the column type to date on the dev to see if it fixes it.

Comment: Looks like we have to create a new column to fix the mistake, later on we will do a col 1 = col 2. Thanks for the input, it really helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that we fixed the date Issue i was able to build my Query for my report
Here is what i was able to do to report on the fiscal year.

```
SELECT Technician, Count(*) as '2016/17 Total',
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART (Month, InstallDate) = 04 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Apr,
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART (Month, InstallDate) = 05 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS May,
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART (Month, InstallDate) = 06 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Jun,
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART (Month, InstallDate) = 07 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Jul,
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART (Month, InstallDate) = 08 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Aug,
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART (Month, InstallDate) = 09 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Sep,
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART (Month, InstallDate) = 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Oct,
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART (Month, InstallDate) = 11 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Nov,
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART (Month, InstallDate) = 12 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Dec,
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART (Month, InstallDate) = 01 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Jan,
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART (Month, InstallDate) = 02 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Feb,
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART (Month, InstallDate) = 03 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Mar
FROM Hardware_RefreshData
Where InstallDate between '2016-04-01' and '2017-03-31' 
GROUP BY Technician
ORDER BY Technician desc;
```

Thanks for the input :)